# Semantics of Thread.currentThread() on multicore/multi processor systems?

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore

If running on a multicore or multi processor machine where the jvm has the potential to run more than one thread absolutely simultaneously (not just apparent simultaneously), what does the api method `java.lang.Thread.currentThread()` return?....in the above scenario, does it just return one of the current threads at random?

Comment: `Thread.currentThread()` returns a reference to the thread you are invoking `Thread.currentThread()` within it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns the thread you are currently running inside. If you have two cores and two threads `A` and `B` running completely concurrently, calling this method at the same time, it will return `A` and `B` appropriately.

Your understanding is kind-of correct - the thread returned by this method is always running - because it must be called from some thread and in order to return, it must be running. Don't think about this method in terms of: "*all currently running, non-paused, non-blocked threads*". Instead its meaning is: "*give me a reference to the thread that runs me*".

Comment: "give me a reference to the thread that runs me" -- actually sums it up perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

It makes perfect sense. It returns a reference to the thread that is executing the calling code.

So, suppose that you have two threads, `threadA` and `threadB`. If code running in `threadA` calls `currentThread()`, then `threadA` will be returned. Likewise, If code running in `threadB` calls `currentThread()`, then `threadB` is returned.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) is pretty weak in my view. It states:

> Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.

The use of "currently" here is very poor. Currently is often interpreted to mean "at this instant in time". Which is what confused you.

Rather ironically, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989170.aspx) (!) documentation makes a better stab at it:

> Gets the `Thread` object that is calling the current code block.

But they still fall into the trap of using "current". Oh the pitfalls of writing technical documentation!

Comment: I totally have to shift how I think about statics in this way, thanks

Answer (score 3):

`jvm has the potential to run more than one thread absolutely simultaneously`

Yes, it is true. In a multicore / multiprocessor system it is possible to have more than one currently running thread.there are  some background threads running in the JVM which you have on every system even in `single processor` system also.

The purpose of the method `java.lang.Thread.currentThread()`  is to return the Thread object that is running the current code that calls the method.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.Thread.currentThread()` returns the thread in which is executed the method holding your code.

That doesn't mean at all that no other threads are running at the same time.

If you want to see the difference, you may iterate on all currently running threads with this piece of code :

```
for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
    if (t.getState()==Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
          // see !
    }
}
```

(or simply [count them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536938/how-to-check-the-number-of-currently-running-threads-in-java/11537026#11537026))

Answer (score 0):

It returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: "Currently executing" is somewhat vague.

Comment: Yes. The documentation is vague.

Answer (score 0):

> does the api method java.lang.Thread.currentThread() returning just one thread no longer make sense

It *only* makes sense if you have multiple threads. It return the thread currently running the code.  Something you can't obtain any other way.