# What is the currently running thread on a multicore processor?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read that `sleep()` puts the currently running thread to sleep. Is this valid for multi-core processors also? I am not sure, but it think a multi-core processor would have multiple "currently running threads".

Comment: I would expect it to affect the thread which executes the specific piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that Sleep() puts the currently running thread to sleep. Is this valid for multi core processors also?

Yes. `sleep(...)` would put it's executor thread for the sleep for the time passed as argument.

> but it think a multi core processor would have multiple "currently running threads".

True. A multicore processor will have more than one threads running at same instant of time.

> What is the currently running thread on a multicore processor?

See this: [Semantics of Thread.currentThread() on multicore/multi processor systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216853/semantics-of-thread-currentthread-on-multicore-multi-processor-systems)

`Thread.CurrentThread()` will be executed on certain thread. The same thread will be returned irrespective of that on which processor it is running.

Answer (score 0):

sleep only puts the thread to sleep on which it was called.

And yes, that's also true on multi-core processors as multi-threading doesn't necesarily require a multicore pc. A single core processor can hanle multiple processes as well, can't it?

Comment: It can, but it fakes the concurrency by timeslicing and other techniques. In a single core CPU there is always only one currently running process and only one currently running thread. Wikipedia has a nice page about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitasking

Comment: i know that :). I just wanted to make him think. And for the purpose of his question I didn't want to go deep into detail.

Answer (score 0):

An OS gives 'directions' to a core, or more. So e.g. Windows can give direction to multiple cores. Windows can run multiple processes. Time slicing gives each process a certain amount of time to perform its task. That is, a process is given a certain amount of time to perform its calculations on the core. As Windows (in this example) is preemptive (as so is linux), it will decide which process will be put on the core and for how long. 
Now a process can have multiple threads. Each thread is like a single 'process' on the CPU. So again, a pre emptive OS decides which thread runs when. On a quad (4) core, you can only run 4 process/threads at the same time. On a single core you would be able to run 4 processes as well, but only one at the time.

**Example**:

When you have 4 processes with each 2 threads on a quad core. Windows can decide to put one process on each core. Windows will decide that each core will switch between the 2 threads of the process that is assigned to that core. Now when you put one of those two threads to Sleep, Windows does not have to switch between threads for the time you have put your thread to sleep, and can spent all its time performing one thread. While at the same time the switching of threads continues for the other 3 processes that where loaded on the other cores.

Of course its far more complex than I summarized above.