# Java multithreading: sleep and currentThread methods

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I'm new to concurrent programming in Java. I've noticed that the methods sleep() and currentThread() of the Thread class are static. Since with a multi-core CPU, many threads can run at the same time, I was wondering how the thread is chosen between the ones in execution. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. I found another SO post that explains this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easily found in the [Javadocs for `Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

For `currentThread()`:

> Returns a reference to the **currently executing thread object**.

For `sleep()`:

> Causes the **currently executing thread** to sleep

I.e. the `Thread` that calls the method for both methods.

Comment: I still don't understand. Suppose I have a quad-core CPU with 4 threads running at the same time. When I call Thread.sleep(), which one is sent to sleep? Thread-0, Thread-1, Thread-2 or Thread-3? How does the thread scheduler make the choice? Thank you.

Comment: The thread scheduler does not come into the picture to choose which one sleeps.  Whichever thread calls `Thread.sleep()` will put itself to sleep.

Comment: Who works - he eats. Which thread calls - that thread sleeps. (And it's always :).)