# Thread imageView update speeds up

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread that is used to spin an imageview as other things happen in the background. It works great for spinning, but I've noticed as I turn it on and off (based on the spinningMain variable) the button starts to spin faster and faster and faster.
I'm unsure what the cause of this is as the thread is told to sleep every 100ms.
If it helps I also have another thread (runnable thread) which runs the main code in between, which I was wondering whether it was disrupting the thread?

The imageView update thread is:

```
            final Thread t = new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        while (!isInterrupted()) {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (spinningMain == true) {
                                        // update TextView here!
                                        if (spinningAngleMain >= 360) {
                                            spinningAngleMain = 0;
                                        } else {
                                            spinningAngleMain += 5;
                                        }
                                        imageButton.setRotation(spinningAngleMain);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
```

And the Second thread is pretty much made as follows

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (searchStateButton == true) {
            //do all my stuff
            }
```

My boolean variables are set to volatile if that helps as well.

Comment: Check the set of running threads and make sure you don't have several of them running at once (each incrementing the angle).

Comment: Hi, I tried checking how many threads are running from info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536938/how-to-check-the-number-of-currently-running-threads-in-java From what I understand, it seems to go from 1 to 7 threads. Although sometimes the thread will be at 5 and it will spin fast, and other times it will be at 5 and spin slowly. So I'm not quite sure I get it, although just the fact that I have on average of 5 threads must mean some are being called multiple times right? Otherwise it should be either 2 or 3?

Comment: I tried using a static volatile boolean around the runOnUiThread to only run if the thread itself isn't already running. But I still unfortunately get a pretty big speed up. Using a Thread.sleep of 1000 which I'm assuming would be ms (So 1 Second) gets me updates which look like to be about 200ms or less.